# Returning the highest value of an array after inputting 5 numbers

Tags: javascript

I am creating an array by imputing 5 different scores.  Now, I am suppose to return the highest score from that particular array.  However, after I am done imputting my last score, I am getting the following message: **"Highest score: undefined"**

Can someone point out as to why this is occuring and help me out?  I am currently learning JS.

```
var arrScores = [];     //I created an empty array where my scores will be stored.                            

//Here I am creating a loop so that the user can input 5 scores
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {             
  arrScores.push(prompt('Please enter your score ' + (i+1))); 
}
//I created a function thinking I would be able to pull the largest score. 
function highestScore(arr){
    highestScore = Math.max(arrScores)
}
//This is suppose to be the final alert with the highest score. 
alert('Highest score: ' + highestScore.join);
```

Comment: `highestScore` isn't an array, you don't need to use `join`.

Comment: It should be `Math.max(...arrScores)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highest score is a function. first you will need to call it

```
alert('Highest score: ' + highestScore(arrScores));
```

And to get the value you will need to return the value from the highestScore function

```
function highestScore(arrScores){
    highestScore = Math.max(...arrScores)
    return highestScore
}
```

Shorter method

```
function highestScore(arrScores){
    return Math.max(...arrScores)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of small mistakes in the code.

1. highestScore is a function, you have to call the function like `highestScore(<parameter>)`
2. You need to spread the array in `Math.max`
3. Add the return statement in the `highestScore` function.
4. You don't need to use the join, as the function will return only the max value.

I have made few changes in the code, try the below code.

Try this.

```js
var arrScores = [];                        
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {             
  arrScores.push(prompt('Please enter your score ' + (i+1))); 
}

function highestScore(arr){
    return Math.max(...arr);
}

alert('Highest score: ' + highestScore(arrScores));
```